# LSTM cannot predict well when the ground truth is near zero

Tags: time-series, pytorch, lstm, prediction

While training the LSTM model, I encountered one problem that I couldn't solve. To begin with, let me describe my model: I used a stacked LSTM model in Pytorch with 3 layers, 256 hidden units in each layer to predict human joint torques and joint angles from EMG features. After the training, the model can predict well when the ground truth is far away from 0, but when the ground truth is near zero, there is always an offset between the predicted value and the ground truth. I guess the reason would be that the large value of ground truth will give more impact during the training process to reduce the loss function.

This is the result:

The prediction for the validation set
[image: Validation Set]

The prediction for the training set
[image: Training Set]

As you can see from the figures, in both datasets, the model can predict well when the ground truth is above 20 degrees. I have tried with different loss functions but the situation did not improve. Since I am just a beginner in this field, I hope someone can point out the problem in my method and how to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Did you normalize the data between [0,1] before passing it to the LSTM?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did normalize the data as you suggested.

Comment: Does the figure show the prediction on the training set or validation set, Minh?

Comment: This is the prediction of the validation set. I have added the prediction for the training set.